# Cangjie typing question

Tags: spelling

when I type 竹尸心 on my phone (Android/gboard) It automatically suggests 怎, when I type the same combination on my Chromebook, the only suggestions are 憅, & 㦾. Are there different versions of cangjie or something? I'm not studying Chinese. I'm only learning the characters to use for "hwayih woen"/华裔文, so pinyin isn't an option. It's a system to write English phonetically with Chinese characters. "仒玍旯侣唼" would be "English".